# UML Circular reference with both aggregation and composition

Tags: uml, aggregation, circular-reference

A few days ago a friend pointed out to me that I had a wrong idea of composition in UML. She was completely right, so I decided to find out what more I could have been wrong about. Right now, there is one more thing that I have doubts about: I have a circular dependency in my codebase that I would like to present in UML form. But how.

In my case the following is true:

- Both A and B have a list of C
- C has a reference to both A and B to get information from.
- C cannot exist if either A or B stops to exist
- Both A and B remain to exist after C is deleted from A and/or B

To model this, I've come up with the following UML (I've ommited multiplicities for now, to not crowd the diagram.)

[image]

My question is, is this the right way to model such relations?

Comment: Why the shared aggregation of A/B in C? I guess it's only kind of parent information, so just an association?

Comment: Well, to indicate the last bullet from my bullet list.

Comment: But there is no aggregation as I see it. In general (!) it's just superfluous to show the lifetime of object, keeping in mind that almost all target languages will finally deal with garbage collection or the like.

Comment: So then, what should it look like according to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problems**

Some facts to keep in mind:

- Default multiplicity makes your model invalid. A class may only be composed in *one* other class. When you don't specify multiplicity, you get [1..1]. That default is sad, but true.
- The UML spec doesn't define what open-diamond aggregation means.
- Your model has many duplicate properties. There is no need for any of the properties in the attribute compartments, as there are already unnamed properties at the ends of every association.

**Corrections**

Here is a reworking of your model to make it more correct:

[image]

Notice the following:

- The exclusive-or constraint between the associations means only one of them can exist at a time.
- Unfortunately, the multiplicities allow an instance of `C` to exist without being composed by `A` or `B`. (See the reworked model below.)
- The property names at the ends of all associations explicitly name what were unnamed in your model. (I also attempted to indicate purpose in the property names.)
- The navigability arrows prevent multiple unwanted properties without resorting to duplicative attributes.

**Suggested Design**

If I correctly understand what your model means, here is how I would probably reverse the implementation into design:

[image]

Notice the following:

- Class `D` is abstract (the class name is in italics), meaning it can have no direct instances.
- The generalization set says:

  - An instance cannot be multiply classified by `A` and `B`. (I.e., `A` and `B` are {disjoint}.)
  - An instance of `D` *must* be an instance of one of the subclasses. (I.e., `A` and `B` are {complete}, which is known as a [covering axiom](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_KZMAIp0n8KU/S8cet8cIqpI/AAAAAAAAAUI/GCeiJ7Hp8bQ/s1600/coveringAxiom.JPG).)
- The subclasses inherit the `ownedC` property from class `D`.
- The composing class can now have a multiplicity of [1..1], which no longer allows an instance of `C` to exist without being composed by an `A` or a `B`.

Comment: Re open diamond: spec states "Indicates that the Property has shared aggregation semantics. Precise semantics of shared aggregation varies by application area and modeler.", so yes its "near to" nothing. Re duplicate properties: http://bellekens.com/2011/08/10/uml-best-practice-attribute-or-association/ puts it quite nicely.

Comment: Hey Jim, thanks for clearing things up more, but the design is as it should be. C is not part of A or B, it is always part of A and B. But whenever A is deleted, C gets deleted as well (both from A and B). Also if C is deleted from A, it is also deleted from B. I'm not sure how to apply those constraints in UML form though.

Comment: It cannot be composed by both in UML. It's not possible.

Comment: So it should just be an association then?

Comment: There's no other choice, unless you want to make up a meaning for aggregation.

Comment: I already told her she was correct, but I learned one more thing today thanks to you, haha. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Leave away the open diamonds and make them normal associations. These are no shared aggregations but simple associations. The composite aggregations are ok.

In general there is not much added value in showing aggregations at all. The semantic added value is very low. In the past this was a good hint to help the garbage collection dealing with unneeded objects. But nowadays almost all target languages have built-in efficient garbage collectors. Only in cases where you want an explicit deletion of the aggregated objects you should use the composite aggregation.

Comment: I've updated the accepted answer, because the other is more comprehensive. However, leaving this comment because this answer was helpful as well.

Comment: Yeah, sure. This is the tl;dr